# How to Get Ellipsis When Using 2 Lines of Cell Text in iOS 5

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uitableview

What do I need to do to get ellipsis if the textlabel text exceeds 2 lines? I have pointed out the issue in the screen shot below, followed by the code that sets the textLabel properties. Thanks for looking!

[image]

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

      //...          

      cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
      cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
      cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
      cell.textLabel.text = [self.selectedSubject subject];
      cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"May 21st, 2012";

      return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use

```
cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
```

instead of

```
cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
```

UILineBreakModeWordWrap only works when numberOfLines is equal to 1

Comment: No problem, I had the same problem a few weeks ago

Comment: UILineBreakModeTailTruncation is now deprecated. You have to use NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
```

to

```
cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
```